# Remove Category Uncategorized from Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to list all post from a custom post type by category so I came up with this code (see below) but them I see this uncategorized category I want to remove. I tried in the query `cat=$cat_id&exclude="1"&post_type=locations` but it's not working. Any ideas? Thank You

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    $cats = get_categories();

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
        echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
        query_posts("cat=$cat_id&exclude="1"&post_type=locations");

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif;  ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite old, but I stumbled across it, so in case it is relevant to anyone, here is what I believe the answer is:

Since you are specifying each category by ID, you are trying to exclude the category that you are specifying when it has a term ID of 1. So in the first iteration of the loop, you are saying

```
cat=1&exclude=1&post_type=locations
```

Since you are specifying exactly what you are excluding, I believe the "inclusive" query value outweights the "exclusive" query value. If this is the case, you can instead do it like this (and even save a query!):

```
$cats = get_categories();

foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
    $cat_id = $cat->term_id;

    if ( $cat_id == 1 )
        continue; // skip 'uncategorized'

    echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";

    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_type=locations");

    ?>{the rest}<?php
}
```

Please note, I don't recommend the use of `query_posts`, and instead `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query` should be used instead. Further reading:
https://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/

Answer (score 1):

```
`query_posts( 'cat=-3' );`
```

// 3 is category id you want to exclude
 see more ref. about query_posts [QUERY POSTS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: did you use query_posts("cat= -1"); (with minus sign in front of one)?

Comment: yes I tried exclude=1 and also cat=-1 and even tried category_name

Comment: I was thinking perhaps I should filter it in get_categories(); so I did and the same, no results

Comment: query_posts("cat=-1") works for me to exclude category=1 (Uncategorized), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('exclude' => array(1));
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Please try this I Hope this works. Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The problem are your quotes
try this:

```
 query_posts("cat=$cat_id&exclude=1&post_type=locations");
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you print some debug and show us what is going on?? is complicated to help...have you tried  <?php query_posts( 'cat=-1' );  ?> ?. Have you looked at: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/ ?

Answer (score -3):

TRY THIS ;

Go to Appearance then click on Widget,
Once widget opened, Click on Primary Widget area,
You will see "Category"
Just click on,Hold your left mouse button and move to
"Inactive widget " Group.
When you go back your website, You will not see Uncategorized anymore. :-))

Comment: How in this world does this even solve the issue. Please explain